# How to typedef a forward declaration?

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I need help with declaring some structures to use in my code. The idea is that I need to declare some structures that are included in each other and use typedef to have a good coding style.

I have tried to declare these:

```
typedef struct cell
{
    T_Tree list_of_sons;
    struct cell *next;
}ListCell, *T_List, **Adr_List;

typedef struct node
{
    int value;
    T_List list;
}Node, *T_Tree;
```

It doesn't work because the type "T_Tree" is not declared before, but I would like to find a way to declare them while keeping the type definitions shown above.

Answer (score 3):

Never (except function pointers) hide pointers in the typedef-s. It makes code more error prone and hard to read (you don't know when you see the declaration if something is a pointer or not).

```
struct node;

typedef struct cell
{
    struct node *list_of_sons;
    struct cell *next;
}ListCell;

typedef struct node
{
    int value;
    ListCell *list;
}Node;
```

Comment: Never is a strong word.  There are other times when you want to typedef a struct. In particular, if you want the structure to be opaque and to force that the users always use API. e.g. FILE in stdio.h; implementation of memory pools, or for that matter the file-descriptors returned from the kernel.

Comment: @AhmedMasud `FILE` in stdio is not a pointer. `FILE *fp; fp = fopen (.....)` Only bad windows design lead to `SHANDLE` and another monsters. Hiding the pointers is IMO one of the worst practices in C language.

Comment: I also agree. I think using typedefs really only make sense when the actual type of something might be different. Otherwise, I’ve not seen many cases where typedefs make code any more maintainable.

Answer (score 2):

Insert `typedef struct node *T_Tree;` before the first declaration. Then remove `T_tree` from the last declaration.

That declares `T_Tree` to be a pointer to a `struct node`. You may declare a pointer to a `struct` even though the `struct` does not have a complete definition.